# Can't load textures into Chunky?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to load a texture pack into Chunky, which is a Minecraft rendering software, but when I do so, it simply gives me an error that it failed. I'm trying to load 1.5 Faithful 32x32. Please help!

Comment: For those who don't know what Chunky is, can you elaborate?

Comment: Done. Do you have an answer?

Comment: Do you have a link to the texture pack? The format of texture packs has changed with 1.5 and I'm wondering which it is.

Comment: Also, what version of Chunky do you have?

Comment: The latest I think... I only downloaded it a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem! It's because the texturepack system in minecraft has changed! All the terrain texture files is now individual. And not a single terrain file, The two things you can do is: 1) You can use a texture pack from 1.4 and erlier... Or 2) You can wait until chunky is updated to 1.5! ;)